# SQL Server Dynamic Pivoting - Not Usal Pivot With Count

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, pivot, pivot-table

I need to Pivot Questions With Their Answers.The Desired Output of the pivot Query is below and the table structure too.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image][image]

I have Created the SQL fiddle Here [Sql Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=663406a844e94e7617749f3e1a6bce44). I saw many examples of count with pivot but couldn't find something similar to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need some joins to get the base data and a dynamic `pivot` to show the result in the desired format.

try the following:

```
drop table if exists #temp

--base table with all details
select s.ID SurveyID, s.SubmittedBy, sq.Question, sa.Answer
into #temp
from @Survey s
join @SurveyMaster sm on sm.ID = s.SurveyMasterID
join @SurveyQuestion sq on sq.SurveyMasterID = s.SurveyMasterID
join @SurveyAnswers sa on sa.SurveyQuestionID = sq.ID and sa.SurveyID = s.ID

--dynamic pivot
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.Question) 
            FROM #temp c
            ORDER BY 1 DESC
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT SurveyID, SubmittedBy, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select SurveyID, SubmittedBy, Question, Answer
                from #temp
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(Answer)
                for Question in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

--execution
execute(@query)
```

Please find the db<>fiddle **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=eed37257a769393a7d1a6cfc7e762c7e)**.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @sqlstring as varchar(max) = '';
SELECT
   @sqlstring = STUFF((
   SELECT distinct
      ',' + '[' + isnull(sq.Question, '''') + ']' 
   from
      @surveyanswers sa 
      join
         @SurveyQuestion sq 
         on sq.ID = sa.SurveyQuestionID 
      join
         @survey sv 
         on sv.SurveyMasterID = sq.SurveyMasterID FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')          
         select
            sa.SurveyID,
            sv.SubmittedBy,
            sq.Question,
            sa.Answer into ##temp 
         from
            @surveyanswers sa 
            join
               @SurveyQuestion sq 
               on sq.ID = sa.SurveyQuestionID 
            join
               @survey sv 
               on sv.SurveyMasterID = sq.SurveyMasterID 
         set
            @sqlstring = 'SELECT  SurveyID,SubmittedBy,' + @sqlstring + '  FROM   (select * from  ##temp ) t ' + ' PIVOT ( ' + ' max(Answer)  FOR Question IN (' + @sqlstring + ' ) ) AS pivot_table' execute(@sqlstring);
```

RESULT:
[image]